# How can I created a rounded corner box without using CSS3?

Tags: css, background

I have to create a rounded box by background images.

My CSS code is:

```
background-image: url('/images/content/center/top.png'), url('/images/content/center/grad.png'), url('/images/content/center/cont.png');
background-position: top center, bottom center, center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I have to make the centered 1px line to fill the free space (by CSS).
I'm not allowed to use `box-radius` (CSS3) because of IE.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't multiple backgrounds already a CSS3 property ?

Comment: See this [article](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers).  Specifically the part about IE.

Comment: Internet Explorer (up to 8) doesn't [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20background) multiple `background-image`s.

Comment: So what should I do, to work in IE8 too?

Comment: You'll have to wrap your `<div>` in two more `<div>` tags. Then, you set the background for each `<div>` individually.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could use CSS3PIE (http://css3pie.com) to enable border-radius for IE.

Comment: PIE is not working here. when I add the behaviour, the BG doesn't show up (IE8)

Answer (score 0):

Your center background isn't repeating:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

Change it to `repeat-y` and see what happens:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y, no-repeat;
```

Also, you *do* know this won't work at all with IE8 and below?

Comment: Btw, the center is the last, but when I change this to repeat-y, it'll fill the rounded borders too, and I'll be a rectangle.

Comment: That's going to happen. The backgrounds aren't "smart", so they don't scale like you want them to. You'll have to make your element split up into a top part, a bottom part, and a center.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you markup is, if I had to support all browsers I would lay out my code like this.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="top"></div>
   <div class="middle">ALL your text goes in here</div>
   <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And css like this

```
.container{
   width:300px;
}
.top, .bottom{
   width:100%;
   height:30px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.top{
   background-image:url;
   }
.bottom{
   background-image:url;
   }
.middle{
   width:100%;
   display:block;
   background-image:url;
   background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: I can't do this, because I have a gradient at bottom.